# Video for everybody with modernizr not working?

Tags: html, video, modernizr

I have a webpage coded in html5 using tags like `header`, `footer`, `section` and `video`.
I use modernizr to support those tags in IE 7 and IE 8.

There's a video in the page including flash fallback (video for everybody).

When I test the page in IE 8, the page is well rendered, including tags specific to html5.

The problem is that the flash fallback for the video doesn't work. I have a black area instead of the flash player.

It works only if I remove the script tag to load modernizr. If I build a custom version of modernizr without html5 shim, the flash player loads and I can play the video, but html5 tags are not recognized.

How can I use video for everybody with modernizr / html5 shim ?
Why isn't it working?

Thanks for your help

---

Update :

To go further in details, my page is based on html5boilerplate and use mediaelementsjs for the player.

Here's the html code

```
<head>
...
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
...
</head>

<body>

...

<video width="332" height="250" poster="img/poster.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/myvideo.mp4" />
    <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="video/myvideo.webm" />
        <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
        <object width="332" height="250" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http://.../img/poster.jpg',{'url':'http://.../video/myvideo.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}">
        <!-- Image as a last resort -->
        <img src="img/poster.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="Your browser doesn't support video" />
        </object>
    </video>

...

<script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

And what is in script.js

```
$(function() {

if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<=7) {
    // $("video, audio").mediaelementplayer({defaultVideoWidth: 332,defaultVideoHeight: 250, features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume','fullscreen']});
    }
    else {
    // initialize scrollable
        $(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true, mousewheel: true}).navigator();
        $("video, audio").mediaelementplayer({defaultVideoWidth: 332,defaultVideoHeight: 250, features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume','fullscreen']});
    }
});
```

The plugins.js file contains the code of mediaelement-and-player.min.js
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/build/mediaelement-and-player.js

It works in IE 8 only if I comment the line to load modernizr.

Comment: If you include some code or post it here http://jsfiddle.net/ this will help people help you ....

Comment: Seems a bit confused, why use MediaElementJs if you're manually specifying the flash fallback player and using another player? MEJS is a shim that includes the flash component... anyway, isn't it because the swf you're including isn't on the same domain perhaps? Also, doesn't the msie and version check in the script defeat the purpose of feature shims in the first place? And if you use modernizr the video tag is suddenly supported and the object tags inside will react differently, shouldn't they then have noscript tags as a workaround for non-script browsers... my head is spinning ^^

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need to use "Video for Everybody"?

We use [http://mediaelementjs.com](http://mediaelementjs.com/) in conjunction with pages marked up with HTML5 and using Modernizr with no problems across all OS/Browsers

Comment: No, I don't need specifically "video for everybody", but to keep my question simple, I mentioned "video for everybody" instead of mediaelelmentjs, because it describes the same html code.

Comment: Could you post a part of your code? I use modernizer and mediaelementsjs but it doesn't work with IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple javascript libraries use `jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also suspected of modernizr but was FitVids. FitVids was messing with "embed" objects after `MediaElement.js` have already done its magic.

To fix this, I needed to ensure that any `jQuery().fitVids()` ever happened **before** `jQuery('video,audio').mediaelementplayer()`.